# FBConnect - sessionValid - AFTER delete application at the facebook-website

Tags: ios, facebook, session

In my iOS iPhone app I use facebook connect. The SSO works wonderfully, I can post to wall etc., But there is one problem:

1. I start my app
2. allow facebook to connect
3. everything is fine in the app 
   BUT NOW ...
4. I delete the application on the facebook website!
5. If I start my app now - the NSLOG says, the FB-Connections is OK. ..?

So I thought, If I delete the applications online in my account, the iphone app has NO validSession and has to ask for a new login, but this failed.

What is wrong? How can I check that in the right way? Or how log is the sessionValid? Is there a timelimit before the method will run again? So was my check (delete online, start app again) to quick?

---- UPDATE:

```
- (void)fbLogin:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"FB Login Alert");

    [self checkForPreviouslySavedAccessTokenInfo];    
    if (!isConnected == YES) {              
        NSLog(@"NO - Facebook Connection");

        UIAlertView *popupFacebook =  [[UIAlertView alloc]                     
                                      initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Headline_FacebookL", @"Headline")
                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"Facebook-Text", @"Facebook") 
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"later",@"Facebook Login später")
                                  otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Facebook",@"Login"), nil];
    popupFacebook.tag = alertFacebook;
    [popupFacebook show];
    [popupFacebook release];

}
    else{
        NSLog(@"Facebook Connection OK");
    }

}


(void)checkForPreviouslySavedAccessTokenInfo:

-(void)checkForPreviouslySavedAccessTokenInfo{
// Initially set the isConnected value to NO.
isConnected = NO;
NSLog(@"FB Status erst mal auf NEIN");

// Check if there is a previous access token key in the user defaults file.
appDelegate.facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"XXXXXXXXX" andDelegate:(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    appDelegate.facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    appDelegate.facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}  

    // Check if the facebook session is valid.
    // If it’s not valid clear any authorization and mark the status as not connected.
if (![appDelegate.facebook isSessionValid]) {
        //[facebook authorize:permissions];
        isConnected = NO;
        NSLog(@"FB NO");
    }
    else {

        isConnected = YES;
        NSLog(@"FB YES");
    }
}
```

SWITCH:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"clicking");
    //NSString *title = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if (alertView.tag == alertWelcome )  {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            NSLog(@"close");
        }
    }  

    else if (alertView.tag == alertFacebook )  {

        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            NSLog(@"später");
        }  

        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            //self.label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Facebook",@"Login"),
            [self fbActive:nil];
            NSLog(@"Login to FB");
        }  

    }
}
```

Permissions:

```
-(void)fbActive:(id)sender{

    if (![appDelegate.facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"user_likes", 
                                @"read_stream",
                                @"user_status",
                                @"publish_stream",
                                //@"publish_actions",
                                //@"manage_pages",
                                @"read_requests",
                                nil];
        [appDelegate.facebook authorize:permissions];
        NSLog(@"FB - Permissions");
        [permissions release];   
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain this " NSLOG says, the FB-Connections is OK" more ?

Comment: I mean my NSLog(@""); ;-) So Xcode run the into --if (![appDelegate.facebook isSessionValid])...ELSE NSLog(@"FB-Connections is OK") , I thougt he has to stop befor -ELSE- where NSLog(@"FB-Connections is NOT OK").

Comment: thanks GOD you edited your comment :-) i thought you don't have an else statement . thats weird any way .. are you using the offline_access permission ?! or anyway did you tried to post something and it did !

Comment: I updated some code... Thats NEW : -offline_access permission-; After deliting on the website->If I want to post to wall etc. the normal login-screen is shown, not the SSO login-screen...