# Facebook post after facebook app has been deleted from the account

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a facebook post feature in an ios app I am writing and everything works regarding login and posting.

Problem is that if I delete the facebook app from the facebook account and then try to post again I do not receive any response from facebook.

I implemented the necessary delegates `FBSessionDelegate` and `FBRequestDelegate` and put logs in each method so I can see if something good or bad happens.

Again, before deleting the facebook app all worked as expected (including of course posting more than once) and the delegate methods indeed were called (I verified that each method does indeed being called in the appropriate scenario).

I came upon this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698061/ios-fbconnect-sessionvalid-after-delete-application-at-the-facebook-websit) on SO but it talks about valid session and I do not think it is relevant in this scenario since I can repost easily if I do not delete the facebook app

Comment: are you checking for an error response from the post action ?  There should be something like 200 permission error

Comment: yes, all the request delegate methods are called. I even tried to send an invalid request to validate that indeed the request:didFailWithError: method is called